# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found. Already added connector jar to Tomcat's lib folder

Tags: java, html, mysql, eclipse, servlets

Using Tomcast 6.0 with Eclipse Java Jee Neon. I already put the jar in tomcast's lib like so: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar"

What else could be causing this issue? Would really appreciate the help!

My code (Servlet):

```
package Servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;


import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String lastname = req.getParameter("lastname");
        String cedula = req.getParameter("cedula");

        try {
            InsertClient(name, lastname, cedula);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        resp.getWriter().println("<html>");
        resp.getWriter().println("<head>"); 
        resp.getWriter().println("<title>Cliente agregado!</title>");
        resp.getWriter().println("</head>");
        resp.getWriter().println("<body>");
        resp.getWriter().println("Cliente fue agregado.");
        resp.getWriter().println("</body>");
        resp.getWriter().println("</html>");
    }

    public static void InsertClient(String Name, String Lastname, String Cedula) throws Exception{      
        try{
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb", "root", "1990");

            PreparedStatement insert = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Cliente(Nombre, Apellido, Cedula) VALUES ('"+Name+"', '"+Lastname+"', '"+Cedula+"')");

            insert.executeUpdate();

        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
        finally{System.out.println("Insertion complete.");}


    }   

}
```

Comment: Tomcat path is relative. By default it uses eclipse metadata and not servers actual location. Open your server settings and change server location to its actual location. That way it will refer to tomcat's lib directory. I hope this helps.

Comment: Your project is dynamic web project. For accessing the jars please put the mysql java connector jar in WEB-INF/libs folder. Or if you are doing it in some IDE add jar by configuring your build path.

Comment: Omg @user1211 , you got it! Just had to right click my project>Properties>Server>Select "Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost" instead of the default <None>. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dynamic Web Project to create your project you must add all your jar files under Web-Inf lib folder. Hope this helps.

Comment: But I'm using tomcat. Wouldn't it need to grab the jars from tomcat's classpath instead?